# is there a postfix relocation service?

Tags: debian, postfix, dovecot

since i am running out of disk space on my debian server, i bought a usb raid and mounted it in the system under "/raid".
I now want to move the whole postfix email directory "/var/vmail" to "/raid/var/vmail".
I could now change in the following files

> /etc/postfix/main.cf
> /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf
> /etc/dovecot/dovecot-mysql.conf

the directory, but I remember from before that there was a postfix service for that.
There was something, wasn't there?

Comment: Instead of messing with configuration files you could move the files and then [bind mount](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount) the new directory under the old directory, i.e. `mount -o bind /raid/var/vmail /var/vmail`.

Comment: Is [**postconf**](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.1.html) (Postfix configuration utility) what are you referring to?

Comment: @CristianCiupitu yes :) that's also posible , thanks for the answer

Comment: is there a system variable like `$virtual_mailbox_base` that can be queried from the bash shell ?

Comment: I have no idea, but you could run `postconf | grep /var/mail`. On my machine it returns `mail_spool_directory = /var/mail`, so you would need to change the `mail_spool_directory` parameter.